# Static barButtonItems in a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve the following. My application when launches goes to the following tableview:

[image: First TVC]

When you select a category, a segue to another tableview is made and looks like this:

[image: Second TVC]

What I want to do, is eventually have the 'Basket' barButtonItem in the first view to update with the total price of the basket amount. I also want the button to be visible from the entire navigation controller cycle.

Is there a way that I can have the Basket button show on every stage of the navigationcontroller process?

So for example I'd like to have the button show on the second table view.

Comment: You created naviagtion controller programatically or by using storyboard?

Comment: I used a storyboard.

Comment: ok , how you are showing Basket on first ViewController ?

Comment: I had dragged the bar button directly into the UINavigationItem at the top of the TVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve it by use of take class of `UINavigationController` like below

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: Private Functions
    private func addRightBarButtonTo(viewController: UIViewController){    
        barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Basket", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(CustomNavigationController.dismiss(_:)))
        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: UINavigationController Delegate
    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.addRightBarButtonTo(viewController)
    }

    @objc func dismiss(sender: Any){
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Use `CustomNavigationController` as rootView Controller of the Window.

## Second Way

Take extension of `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addRightButtonItem() {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Basket", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(barButtonMethod(_:)))
    }
    
    @objc func barButtonMethod(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

and call below method in viewWillAppear of each and every viewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      
        self.addRightButtonItem()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I should have said, I used a storyboard and had dragged my barbutton directly into the first TVC.

Comment: Not sure but I think you should not achieve it by storyboard. There is only way to achieve otherwise you should take extension of UIViewController and add BarButtonItem at right side and call this method in each and every view conroller.

Comment: Either you have to drag/drop bar item in every controller or use above code..
Better way is to use code for reusability purpose

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm just a bit confused as to where 'barButtonItem' is created above? Do I create that within each TVC?

Comment: I will update with second way with extension of UIViewController

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the patience and support.

Comment: @JamLis check my second way and if it will helps then accept answer and close it.